# How to autorun crons?

Tags: bash, cron, centos

I'm trying to get a file to be automatically run by crontab, contents like so:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

*/5 * * * * php /path/to/script
```

I've put this file called `prod.cron` into the `/etc/cron.d` folder but can't seem to get it to run on it's own.  Running the script directly via command line shows that it works okay, but not sure if the files in cron.d get auto detected or do I need to do something else to init them?

Comment: Do you have user `php` on your system? 6th field of crontabs is login name.

Comment: You should "submit" cronjobs via `crontab -e` (as the user under whom's id the cronjob has to be run), not by putting files in /etc or /var. check out `man crontab`

Comment: Yes, I've used crontab before, but I'm trying something different here.  There are cron.* folders that will auto run scripts for you without requiring to edit the crontab, that' what I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: Don't think you need a user there, I see tons of examples just doing something like `*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/script`

Comment: did you `chmod +x` your `/etc/cron.d/prod.cron`?

Comment: @X.Jacobs: cron files are not directly executed; 444 or 644 permission would be enough.

Comment: @wildplasser:  Personally, I never use `crontab -e`; it makes it too difficult to keep track of changes. I keep my crontab file in a source control system, and use `crontab filename` to install it.

Comment: Rob: This question is better suited for the unix site (where it may well be a duplicate). I'm going to flag it for migration. When/if it's migrated, you should get a notification. You'll probably want to set up an account on the unix site, which is easy to do.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Agreed. The risk of `crontab -e` is that the 'r' key is *very close* to the 'e' key on the keyboard ;-[ I tend to keep a (more or less) recent copy handy somewhere near the user/application 's cron script. But putting it under rcs might be needed in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that directory `/etc/cron.d` is intended to be used by packages, crontabs should be installed into an users crontab. That being said, check out the following [Cron Issues](http://livecronjobs.com/):

> 1. The script is not having execute permissions. Use chmod a+x  to provide permissions.
> 2. In the case of php, perl or other scripting language, the path to interpretor or program is not correct. Always provide actual path to
>      the interpretor while defining command to run in cron. To find out
>      where the program is located, use whereis  command. For e.g.
>      for php, whereis php. for perl, whereis php, etc.
> 3. The environment variables required to run the script are unavailable. The cron doesn't use the same environment of a user. It
>      uses its own environment while running the commands. So the variables
>      defined in .login or .profile are not visible to him. The most common
>      issue is related to PATH variable which is not similar.

Answer (score 0):

There are two flavors of cron file.

Files installed under `/etc/cron.d` are *system* cron files. They require the 6th field on each line to be the user account used to run the command. See other files under `/etc/cron.d` for examples.

Non-system cron files just have the usual 5 fields to specify when the job runs, followed by the command to run. They're installed by the `crontab` command, executed by the user account that will run the command(s). This is *probably* what you wnat to use.

Either add `root` as the 6th field of the relevant line, or run `crontab prod.cron` as root (or as whatever account should run the command).

And of course make sure the `php` command is in the specified `$PATH`.